# Fetch commission of related Designer for each ordered Product in admin Dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, database

We have lot of Designers in site (Seller/ Vendor). we assigned each product to one **Designer**.

we are displaying all the orders in custom page : **www.1234.com/php/site6/orders.php**

if we login as **admin** we can see **all orders** in page .

if we login as **Designer1**, than we can see all orders that contains **Designer1's** Products.

Now, **Product 1** belongs to **Designer1 [kidsdial2]**

if any customer buy `Product 1` than we will give commission to `Designer1` & we need to display commission for designer in Orders.php page for that particular product in both admin & Designer Dashboard.

we are saving `commission` of each designer in **tbl_users** table

[image]

**example**: in above image , we assigned **"10" as commission for Kidsdial2  Designer** . so if any Kidsdial2's product bought by customer, than we need to display "10" as commission for that Ordered Product in both **Designer & admin Dashboard.**

**Edit 2**

in **Designer account [kidsdial2]** commission value is displaying correct value .but when i logged in with **admin account [kidsdial1]** , **commission is displaying as "5"** for  **admin dashboard** because for "kidsdial1" we are saving commission as 5 in Database. But as Product belongs to "Kidsdial2", it **should display "10" instead of 5 in admin dashboard too**.

**Designer Dashboard**

**[image: Designer dashboard]**

**admin Dashboard**

[image]

```
if($accountType == "admin")
{ 

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where userID=:uid"); 
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;

$responce[] = array( 
$commission
); 
}
```

**related code** :

```
foreach($order as $orderData) 
{ 
$k = 0; 
$orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id']; 
$orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems); 

while ($k < count($orderitemsarray))    
{ 

if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0') 
{ 

$productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]); 
$designer_id = $productdetail->getDesignerID() ; 

if($accountType == "admin")
{ 

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where userID=:uid"); 
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;

$responce[] = array( 
$commission, 
); 
}
```

**Edit 1**  [ Ignore this part, Solved with help of Murtuza's answer ]

i need to display  commission value of Designer for that order [row] at last column.

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where userID=:uid");
```

Comment: Why do you keep opening a bounty for this question ? You already accepted an answer and assigned two different bounties to two other answers

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Thanks for your comment, today only i got an answer , other old answers didt worked for me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you can use this way May be you can achieve what you want

```
    /* Murtuza */

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where userID=:uid  "); //I assume user_id is field of database in tbl_user table
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $productdetail->getDesignerID() ));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;
```

**edit**

Finally find out your problem

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;
```

Comment above code start line no 289

Comment: sorry, still its displaying `5` only as commission....

Comment: is `userID` is your primary key in database ?

Comment: yes, you are right.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento `echo $designer_id;` and check what data you get

Comment: i am getting this : `66666666894545448958444`

Comment: 23 charactars are displying , each are designer id of one designer..... total 23 rows displaying

Comment: @BabyinMagento Yes you are getting Right data, so where is the actual problem could you tell me

Comment: actual issue is i am using wrong logic here, i am displaying commission by according to associated value of all users as you can see in image i uploaded in question,  , but i should try to get commission based on product basis , not by fetching `commission1` column...

Comment: is this [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders2.php) is still not visible for you ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento please check my updated answer or paste you new code link

Comment: still same result : `5` , pls check full code : http://pastebin.com/RXKSEsyW

Comment: @BabyinMagento Please check my updated answer

Comment: when you said `finally found solution`, i thought it will not work again, but it worked, the level of your confidence is taller than sky, i can give bounty after 24 hours, Thanks.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento OK give me some time I will understand that problem and let you know

Answer (score 5):

in your above code

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
```

replace with below

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where user_id=:uid  "); //I assume user_id is field of database in tbl_user table
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
```

**you can do below code to your requirement**

```
if($accountType == "admin")
{ 
$designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")";


   $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where name=:designername  "); //I assume user_id is field of database in tbl_user table
$stmt->execute(array(":designername" => $designerName ));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;

$responce[] = array( 
$orderData->getIncrementId() , 
$orderData->getIncrementId() , 
$orderitemsarray[$k], 
$productdetail->getName() , 
$designerName, 
$orderData['status'],              // magento  [ pending / processing/complete]
$orderData['grand_total'],         // magento
$orderData['customer_email'],      // magento
$data['commission'],
$paid_status,
$sDate                             // magento
); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks, now its fetching only one designer commission & displaying `0` at the last row of the table.   http://prnt.sc/dk35zx   but i need to display commission for each `ordered products row` in last column. please help me for this.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento check my updated answer

Comment: sorry, still its giving me same result as before.....

Comment: do you want me to remove code under `/* code to fetch commissin */` in question.....

Comment: is i need to use only 1 `responce array` or both, right now i am using separate `responce` array for displaying `commission` as i mentioned in question -, here is complete code - > http://pastebin.com/GHEr2bYc

Comment: forget about old code, please check new code here : http://pastebin.com/TV9jU4db

Comment: @BabyinMagento yes after designer name add my code and edit add that data in responce

Comment: what i did is i tried your code under `commission ` part , but still `no commission` values are displaying : http://pastebin.com/TMEPaykS

Comment: @BabyinMagento Have you added commission in response variable and also added that code for particular designer instead of admin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50188/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Answer (score 3):

Table for Admin display

```
date    orderid     product_id      name    seller_id   status      commission
1/1/16  O101        101             P101    1           Paid        5
1/1/16  O101        104             P104    4           Paid        15


//Main order loop
foreach ( $orders as $order )
{
    $oitems = $order->getItems();
    if(!empty($oitems)) {
        //Order Items foreach
        foreach($oitems as $oitem)
        {
            echo $order->getOrderDate();
            echo $order->getOrderId();

            $pid = $oitem->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
            echo $product->getName();   

            if($accountType  == 'admin') {
                echo $product->getSellerId();
                echo getCommissionByProduct($product);
            } else if($accountType == 'designer' ) {        
                //$user should be already loaded Object designer login
                echo $user->getCommision();
            }

            echo $order->getStatus();

        }
    }   
}

function getCommissionByProduct( $product )
{
    $sid = $product->getSellerId();
    $seller = Mage::getModel('custom/designer')->load($sid);
    if($seller == NULL) {
        return  false;
    }
    $commission = $seller->getCommision();
    return $commission;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, when i treid your code,  i got `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection::getOrderDate() i` in line `echo $order->getOrderDate();`

Comment: please check full code here : http://pastebin.com/ia8AFA6C

Comment: Welcome @BabyinMagento

Answer (score 1):

```
Here you have fetch data according to designer id not user id

if($accountType == "admin")
{ 

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where userID="'.$desiner_id.'""); 
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;

$responce[] = array( 
$commission
); 
}
```

Comment: let me check and get back to you......

Comment: kk because you already getting designer id from order details so basis on that you have to fetch commison

Comment: i tried your code,  now commission is fetching and displaying properly only when there is particular `designer` value in present in `order_Details` table. otherwise under `Designer ` & `commission` column, no values will display....